# I want to separate data from my field in the band detail with a comma and without a comma in the last item on Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

For example, my field has the comma value added by the field pattern:
21, 22, 23, 26,

but I wanted it to be:
21, 22, 23, 26

or go further:
21, 22, 23 and 26

but without the last comma it would be enough.

remembering that this is referring to in the context of ireport.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unlike many here who decide to just deslike instead of helping even though they are experts on the subject. I suggest a solution:
My doubt was that I wanted my field elements to be separated by a comma and not have that annoying comma in the end example:
item1, item2, item3,
I wanted it to look like this:
item1, item2, item3

and the way to go about doing that is:
`$ V {Variable created to format}! = Null? $ V {Variable created to format} + "," + $ V OR F {Variable with your field or your field}: $ V OR F {Variable with your field or your field}`